# How To Get Id on combobox dropdown

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox, c#-3.0

I am making a Windows application and i have a combo box that will let the user type text and when user select text from `autocomplete` list id is not selected

my code :

```
  Customer.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;

  DataTable dt = Globale.ReturnTable("SELECT Id, [NAME] FROM ACTM WHERE (DBCR = 'D') ORDER BY [NAME]");

  Customer.DataSource = dt;
  Customer.ValueMember = "Id";
  Customer.DisplayMember = "Name";
  Customer.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
  Customer.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
  Customer.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

i need id from name from ComboBoxStyle.DropDown not from dropdowlist

Answer (score 0):

> i need id from name from ComboBoxStyle.DropDown not from dropdowlist

[**`ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx) is enum, so you can cast it

```
int id= (int)ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
```

or if you need to find Customer ComboBoxStyle id

```
int id= (int)Customer.DropDownStyle;
```